# Override ngOnDestroy method of a Directive

Tags: angular, directive, mdbootstrap

I use the mdb-pro library and in particular the TabSetComponent. I have a problem with the ngondestroy function of TabDirective. This one realizes : this.tabset.removeTab(this);
I would like to know if there is a way to override the ngondestroy function of the TabDirective to prevent the tab from being removed.
Thanks

Comment: If the Tab is being destroyed, it's probably fraught with danger to leave it in the TabSet.

Comment: The method is called when in fact the whole tabset is going to be destroyed but here what happens with this method is that my 2nd tabset becomes active instead, and this is not the desired behaviour. Indeed, on my 2 tabs, there is a list of items and when you click on one of them you are redirected to another page. There is an enter/leave animation with the next page but because of this ngondestroy method, it happens the following effect: click on an element of the list of the tab 1, the tab is destroyed, the second tab becomes active and animation with the second tab instead of the first tab.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. There is a similar problem described here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8057